# Segment fault on memcpy tcp socket

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, memcpy

I'm writing a client connecting to a server. I got a Segmentation Fault on line 124 memcpy() of the TCP socket. 
With the UDP connection I want to obtain the IP address of a server on the network, then, obtained the IP, I want to connect with it through a TCP connection. The code of the TCP connection itselves works, because in a new file I can compile. I don't understand where the problem is.

```
#include <stdio.h>      
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <ifaddrs.h>
#include <netinet/in.h> 
#include <string.h> 
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <memory.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include "main.h"

int developer=1;
struct myHelloMsg {
    char myIp[25];
    char myID[25];
};
int FindMyIp(char myIpAddr[], char myMask[], char myBroad[]);
int RecvBroadTime(int sockfd, struct sockaddr_in server_addr);
void CheckID(char myUserID[]);

int main() {
    char myIpAddr[25], myMask[25], myBroad[25], myUserID[25]="";
    char otherUserIp[25], otherUserID[25];
    struct myHelloMsg myMsg, rxMsg;
    CheckID(myUserID);
    int checkConnection;
    disconnected: ;
    checkConnection=0;
    if (developer==1) printf("\nSearching for a network..\n");
    while (checkConnection == 0) {
        checkConnection = FindMyIp(myIpAddr, myMask, myBroad);
        if (checkConnection==0) {
            if (developer==1) printf("--Disconnected..\n");
            sleep(5);
        }
    }
    if (developer==1) printf("\n--Connected..\nIP Address\t: %s\n", myIpAddr);
    if (developer==1) printf("Subnet Mask\t: %s\n", myMask);
    if (developer==1) printf("Broadcast IP\t: %s\n", myBroad);

    int i=0;
    for (i=0;i<25;i++) {
        myMsg.myIp[i]=myIpAddr[i];
        myMsg.myID[i]=myUserID[i]; 
    }
    struct hostent *hptr = gethostbyname(myBroad);
    if (hptr == NULL) {
        if (developer==1) printf("Error while transmitting broadcast message..\n");
        return 0;
    }
    // create socket for initial UDP communication
    int sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    struct sockaddr_in server_addr;
    bzero(&server_addr, sizeof(struct in_addr));
    server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_addr.sin_port = htons(5051);
    server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_BROADCAST);
    memcpy(&server_addr.sin_addr, hptr->h_addr_list[0], sizeof(struct in_addr));
    int opt = 1;
    setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BROADCAST, &opt, sizeof(int));
    int error=0;
    if (developer==1) printf("--Contacting other users in the network..\n");
    sendto(sockfd, &myMsg, sizeof(myMsg), 0, (struct sockaddr *) &server_addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
    int foundSomeone=0;
    //try to connect with others for 5 times - because of UDP unreliable connection
    int countTries=0, received=0, lastTry=0;
    while (countTries<5) { 
        foundSomeone = RecvBroadTime(sockfd, server_addr);
        if (foundSomeone == 1) {
            if (developer==1) printf("An answer has been received..\n");
            socklen_t ssize = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
            recvfrom(sockfd, &rxMsg, sizeof(rxMsg), 0, (struct sockaddr *) &server_addr, &ssize);
            received=1;
            countTries=5;
        }
        else if (foundSomeone == 0) {
            if (developer==1) printf("Timeout(%d try)..\n", countTries+1);
            sendto(sockfd, &myMsg, sizeof(myMsg), 0, (struct sockaddr *) &server_addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
            if (countTries==4) {
                lastTry=1;
            }
        }
        else {
            if (developer==1) printf("--Error..\n");
        }
        countTries++;
    }
    if ((lastTry==1)&&(countTries==5)) {
        foundSomeone = RecvBroadTime(sockfd, server_addr);
        if (foundSomeone == 1) {
            if (developer==1) printf("An answer has been received..\n");
            socklen_t ssize = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
            recvfrom(sockfd, &rxMsg, sizeof(rxMsg), 0, (struct sockaddr *) &server_addr, &ssize);
            received=1;
        }
        else if (foundSomeone == 0) {
            if (developer==1) printf("--No one is connected to the current network..\n");
        }
        else {
            if (developer==1) printf("There has been an error while trying to contact other users..\n");
        }
    }
    close(sockfd);
    // someone else is connected to the network
    // i am gonna behave as a client in during the synchronization step
    if (received==1) {
        if (developer==1) printf("Contact made with user %s (%s).\n", myMsg.myID, myMsg.myIp);
        // check if the user belong to friends i am sharing content with
        i=0;
        for (i=0;i<25;i++) {
            otherUserIp[i]=rxMsg.myIp[i];
            otherUserID[i]=rxMsg.myID[i];
        }
        int socktcp = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);  
        struct hostent *hptr_tcp = gethostbyname(otherUserIp);
        struct sockaddr_in server_addr_tcp;
        bzero(&server_addr_tcp, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
        server_addr_tcp.sin_family = AF_INET;
        server_addr_tcp.sin_port = htons(5054);
        printf("a\n");
        memcpy(&server_addr_tcp.sin_addr, hptr_tcp->h_addr_list[0], sizeof(struct in_addr));
        printf("a\n");
        if (connect(socktcp, (struct sockaddr *) &server_addr_tcp, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in))<0) {
            printf("-Error..\n");
        } else {
            printf("Connection with %s established.. Ready for synchronization step..\n", otherUserID);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}


int RecvBroadTime(int sockfd, struct sockaddr_in server_addr) {
    fd_set socks;
    struct timeval t;
    t.tv_sec = 1;
    t.tv_usec = 0;
    FD_ZERO(&socks);
    FD_SET(sockfd, &socks);
    return select(sockfd+1, &socks, NULL, NULL, &t);
}

int FindMyIp(char myIpAddr[], char myMask[], char myBroad[]) {
    struct ifaddrs * ifAddrStruct=NULL;
    struct ifaddrs * ifa=NULL;
    void * tmpAddrPtr=NULL;
    getifaddrs(&ifAddrStruct);
    int i=0, connected=0;
    ifa = ifAddrStruct;
    while (i!=1) {
        if (((ifa ->ifa_addr->sa_family==AF_INET)&&(ifa->ifa_name[0]=='e')&&(ifa->ifa_name[1]=='n')&&(ifa->ifa_name[2]=='1'))||((ifa ->ifa_addr->sa_family==AF_INET)&&(ifa->ifa_name[0]=='e')&&(ifa->ifa_name[1]=='t')&&(ifa->ifa_name[2]=='h')&&(ifa->ifa_name[3]=='0'))) {
            i=1;
            connected=1;
        } else {
            if (ifa->ifa_next == NULL) return connected;
            ifa = ifa->ifa_next;
        }
    }
    tmpAddrPtr=&((struct sockaddr_in *)ifa->ifa_addr)->sin_addr;
    inet_ntop(AF_INET, tmpAddrPtr, myIpAddr, INET_ADDRSTRLEN);
    tmpAddrPtr=&((struct sockaddr_in *)ifa->ifa_netmask)->sin_addr;
    inet_ntop(AF_INET, tmpAddrPtr, myMask, INET_ADDRSTRLEN);
    tmpAddrPtr=&((struct sockaddr_in *)ifa->ifa_broadaddr)->sin_addr;
    inet_ntop(AF_INET, tmpAddrPtr, myBroad, INET_ADDRSTRLEN);
    return connected;
}

void CheckID(char myUserID[]) {
    FILE *fp;
    if((fp=fopen("userData.txt", "r+"))==NULL) {
        printf("Error while opening the file..\n");
    }
    else {
        fscanf(fp, "%25s", myUserID);
        if (strlen(myUserID)==0) {
            printf("First time you open this app..\nInsert your User ID: ");
            scanf("%s", myUserID);
            fprintf(fp, "%-25s", myUserID);
        }
        else {
            printf("Welcome back %s..\n", myUserID);
        }
        fclose(fp);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is line 124 in the code you posted? It is hard to tell.

Comment: This one :) Sorry

memcpy(&server_addr_tcp.sin_addr, hptr_tcp->h_addr_list[0], sizeof(struct in_addr));

Comment: Please do the following: Reduce the code to a bare minimum which is needed to show the error. Try to remove parts of the code at a time until the error disappears, then put the last thing you edited back in. Reducing the code, will already help you find the error, since you can narrow it down this way. In case you reduced as much as you can and still have not found the error, post the reduced code, the output/behaviour you are expecting and the output/behaviour you are getting. See http://homepage1.nifty.com/algafield/sscce.html for more info.

Comment: Is it possible that hptr->h_length == 0?

Answer (score 2):

I'd say it is not possible to resolve a broadcast address using `gethostbyname()`.

---

Also: `gethostbyname()` is obsolete, use `getnameinfo()` instead.

Comment: Thank for all the reply, fore the moment I solved. The problem was the a function that opens a txt file for checking the username of the client. I Solved by changing from if((fp=fopen("userData.txt", "r+"))==NULL) to if((fp=fopen("userData.txt", "rb+"))==NULL). In reality I still can't understand why it gives me the segmentation fault on that memcpy, which is in an other part of the code.